# What's the name for the notification pattern: waiting for the user to respond to a notification before sending the next one?

Tags: notification

Some websites (e.g. some forums) send notifications like this:

1. User asks multiple questions on the site
2. Other users respond to the questions
3. The website only notifies the user once (that there has been some activity since his last interaction with the site)
4. The user logs into the site or interacts with the site
5. More activities happen that the user should be notified of
6. The website sends another single notification to the user

In short instead of sending one notification per each activity and potentially overwhelming or spamming the user, the user is only sent one notification and the system waits for the user to have an interaction with the site before sending the user another notification.

Is there a name for this pattern?